# Nginx URL routing

Tags: nginx, url-routing

I think this is kind of basic stuff, but I'm struggling to find proper guide that would explain these things:

I have a `index.php` file and `nginx` config so that `https://dev.something.com` works ok.

But I need to change `nginx` config so that that address produces blank page, and `index.php` only works from `https://dev.something.com/lists`. I could put `index.php` inside lists directory, but isn't there more subtle solution?

And here's the hard part:
Users should be able to access

```
https://dev.something.com/lists/userName
https://dev.something.com/lists/userName/listName
```

`userName` and `listName` should be used as `GET`-parameters.

Can anyone help how I could achieve this kind of config with `nginx`?

Answer (score -3):

You're asking a few (relatively basic) questions, and I would suggest you start with their free e-book https://www.nginx.com/blog/announcing-oreillys-new-book-nginx-a-practical-guide-to-high-performance/

You can define where nginx looks for index files with the root clause, and though they normally use the URL context relative to the `server`'s root, it can be override in each location.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root

You can use portions of URLs as variables, which can be passed as paramters too.

```
   location = /lists {  # '=' will match exactly, no trailing url
      root  /path/where/index.php/lives;
      try_files $uri /index.php;
    }
   location /lists { # this will match anything under that url
      rewrite ^/lists/(\d+)/?$ /lists?user=$1; # matches username 
      rewrite ^/lists/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ /lists?user=$1&list=$2; # matches username/list
    }

    location /{ #everything else
      root  /path/where/index.html/lives; #index.html is empty file.
      try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! It almost works, but I think your example limits parameter usage to digits? And for some reason the `$_GET` array is empty?

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming user/list IDs, but you can replace \d with any regex capture group that makes sense.
If you have additional arguments you can tack the variable query_string `?&query_string;` on the end of rewrite arguments.